# How do I get the category code of a character that is the value of a control sequence?

Tags: tex-core, catcodes

How can I get the category code of a character that is the value of a control sequence?

If I do this

```
The catcode for A is \the\catcode`A.
```

I get

```
The catcode for A is 11.
```

If I do this

```
\let\abc=A
The catcode for \abc\ is \the\catcode\abc.
```

I get "Missing number, treated as zero."

I *think* I understand it like this:
\abc is replaced with the character code, category code pair <65, 11>, but TeX expects just a number after \the\catcode, so it inserts a 0, then leaves my A hanging around.

Comment: Pity one cannot add a tag for `the`!

Comment: After doing `\let\abc=@`, you can access the catcode of `@` by `\expandafter\SomeMagic\meaning\abc`, where `\SomeMagic` reads the meaning of `\abc` (which is `the character @`), and converts it to the form you want. I see two things you might want: know the catcode of the `@` that is inside `\abc`, or the catcode that the character `@` currently has. Just tell me which one you want and I can write an expandable command for that.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: And how can you access the *character* code of the token `\let` to `\abc`?

Comment: Something like `\long \def \getcharcode #1{\if \space \noexpand #1\expandafter 3\expandafter 2\else \expandafter \expandafter \expandafter \getcharcodeI \expandafter \meaning \expandafter #1\expandafter A\fi } \def \getcharcodeI #1A{\getcharcodeII #1A#1A#1AB} \def \getcharcodeII #1 #2 #3 #4 #5 #6 #7A#8B{\number \`#7 }` should work (try `\getcharcode {\abc}`), but it will choke horribly if given anything else than an explicit or implicit character token.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly Knuth in his wisdom gave only few clues in the TeXBook for cases like this.

In order to understand the error we need to firstly understand the  definition of `\the`, which is for the case of `catcode` `\the<codename><8-bit number>`, where `<codename>` stands for either `\catcode`,
`\mathcode`, `\lccode` etc...

So clearly in this case `catcode` TeX expects a number and hence the error generated in the example provided by the OP.

All solutions provided by the other posts revolve around changing the definition one way or another to produce the required character code number and which I am demonstrating here with some different examples:

The example below will produce the right answer in both cases,

```
% results category 11
\makeatletter
\def\ABC{`@ }
\the\catcode\ABC

% results category 12
\makeatother
\def\ABC{`@ }
\the\catcode\ABC
```

While comparing two tokens using `\ifcat` things become a bit more complicated, if you want to compare two active characters you have to say `\noexpand` - Knuth says so somewhat obscurely in Exercise 20.11!

Consider the following definitions

```
\catcode`[=13 \catcode`]=13
\def[{*}
```

The following will result  True since we comparing `[` with ']' both now being category 13

```
\ifcat\noexpand[\noexpand]  True \else False \fi
```

Also `\ifcat[* True \else False \fi` is True

Since now we have established two facts `\the\catcode` needs a number and if you use an active character, implicitly or explicitly we can understand why the following will all work!

```
\def\abc{`A}
\chardef\abc=65
```

or Joseph's suggestion for comparisons:

```
\let\abc=A
   \ifcat\noexpand\abc A%
     \TRUE
   \else
     \FALSE
   \fi
```

Comment: Stefan is right, it's a bit strange that you include the backtick in the definition of `\ABC`. (Although for illustration purposes it's interesting to see that then you don't need the `\expandafter`, I'm pretty sure that the OP wouldn't want the backtick included: He wants to test some _existing_ macro, I guess.)

Comment: @Henrik you need the backtick so you can use the `\the\catcode\ABC` straight without an error you either have to do it at the definition stage or when typesetting `\the\catcode...`, with an expandafter as per Stefan's example.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me, using `\expandafter`:

```
\def\abc{A}
The catcode for \abc\ is \the\catcode\expandafter`\abc.
```

and prints

> The catcode for A is 11.

Comment: This is not quite what the question asks: you're using an explicit token whereas the example in the question is an implicit token.

Comment: @Joseph: Though Colin used `\let`, the question seemed a bit more general to me, so I made this suggestion in the hope that it might help. The catcode of a character as value of a control sequence is asked for, not the catcode of an implicit token itself.

Comment: It helps a little, but I'm (sadly) still confused. If I have a \cs (perhaps assigned by \futurelet), how can I get the category code of that token?

Comment: @Colin. I've updated my answer to reflect the fact that `\ifcat` is not quite the same as simply trying to get a number out.

Comment: @Stephan you can also use \def\abc{`A}, then you do not need the expandafter!

Comment: @Yiannis: this would affect the normal output of `\abc`.

Answer (score 4):

As the excellent *[TeX by Topic](http://eijkhout.net/texbytopic/texbytopic.html)* gives us a clue in the discussion of `\ifcat`:

> Control sequence tokens are considered to have category code 16, which makes them all equal to each other, and unequal to all character tokens.

This 'magic' category code is not accessible by normal methods. However, things do work with `\ifcat` if you have implicit tokens:

```
\let\ABC=A
\ifcat\noexpand\ABC A%
  \TRUE
\else
  \FALSE
\fi
```

While you do not need the `\noexpand` here, if this were for example part of a `\futurelet` then you would do, in case the test token was expandable.

Comment: this of course will fail the test `\the\catcode\ABC` looking for a number!

Answer (score 3):

```
\chardef\abc=65
The catcode for \abc\ is \the\catcode\abc
```

Comment: For defining, directly writing \chardef\abc=`A is easier, it doesn't require to know the ASCII code.

Comment: Interesting approach, but means that `\abc` can't be expanded and then used in something like `\pdfstrcmp`. I guess it depends on the application!

Comment: it is the same as the already defined \@ne, \tw@, \thr@@. I never used \pdfstrcmp, because I do not need it for PSTricks :-))  But I use \chardef quite often ...