# How to print and assign category codes?

Tags: tex-core

Consider the code below, which after giving me some trouble (especially with catcode 9 and 15), prints all the category codes up to catcode 15.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
\the\catcode`\\  \ control character  \\
\the\catcode`{  \ open curly\\
\the\catcode`}  \ closing curly \\
\the\catcode`$  \ dollar\\
\the\catcode`&  \ alignment\\
\the\catcode`\ 
\ space \\\the\catcode`#  \ sharp\\
\the\catcode`^ \ hat \\
\the\catcode`_ \ underscore \\
\number\catcode`\  \ space \\
\catcode `\y=9
\the\catcode`\y    \ ignored character \\
\the\catcode`a \ letters\\
\number\catcode`@  \ restricted  \\
\number\catcode`~ \ tilde \\
\the\catcode`\%   \ comment\\ 
\catcode`\z = 15 
\the\catcode`\z  \ invalid character \\
\def\test{}
%\catcode `\t=16
\ifcat\test 16  16  control sequence\fi
\end{document}
```

Now, getting TeX to print the catcode 16, has me puzzled. For starters if you uncomment the line, `%\catcode \t=16` you get,

> ```
> ! Invalid code (16), should be in the range 0..15. 
>   l.23 \catcode\t=16
> ```

but, if you test with `\ifcat` a control sequence is definitely equal to category code 16. So my question is, how can I coerce TeX to say sixteen for a control sequence and how come the error message says 16 is an invalid code, but the TeXbook says it is?

Mildy related question [How do I get the category code of a character that is the value of a control sequence?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7411/how-do-i-get-the-category-code-of-a-character-that-is-the-value-of-a-control-seq)

Comment: Where in the TeX Book does it refer to a catcode of 16? I thought there were 16 in total, numbered 0 to 15.

Comment: @Werner Chapter 20, page 209 detailing the if commands.

Comment: Please correct the title to "category code", not character code.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch ny bad! Thanks for picking it up!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's really *no* category code 16. This code is assigned to control sequences (not `\let` to a character) only for the purposes of `\ifcat`.

Similarly, character code 256 is assigned to the same tokens for the purposes of `\if`.

You can get category codes 9 and 15 with

```
\the\catcode`\^^@
\the\catcode`\^^?
```

(these are the only characters that have those category codes in the default setting, bytes 0 and 127).

Notice also that `\ifcat` doesn't compare a token with a number, but *two* tokens:

```
\ifcat ab
\ifcat a1
```

The first evaluates to true, the second to false.

Quoting from the TeXbook, page 209:

> • `\ifcat<token1><token2>` (test if category codes agree)
>   TeX will expand macros following `\if` until two unexpandable tokens are found. If either token is a control sequence, TeX considers it to have character code 256 and category code 16, unless the current equivalent of that control sequence has been `\let` equal to a non-active character token.

The key word is *considers*. Look at page 38:

> A token is either (a) a single character with an attached category code, or (b) a control sequence.

Section 506 of "TeX, the program" tells the truth about this: if the next token is not an active character or is a control sequence (not let to a character), then the variable *cur_chr* gets the value 256.

Comment: Why then this `\ifcat\test 16  true\else false\fi` is true? Where in the TeXbook does it say it is really _no_ category 16? I read it differently on page 209, chapter 20.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides With your definition `\test` expands to nothing; so `\ifcat` compares `1` with `6` and their category codes agree.

Comment: Just thinking aloud this is also one of Knuth's jokes `\ifcat doesn't compare a token with a number, but two tokens` in my `ifcat` test it definitely compares one with two i.e, cs, number,number???? Two numbers are two tokens, right?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides Yes, `16` is two tokens and they are unexpandable, so the expansions triggered by `\ifcat` stop. It's not like `\ifcat#=4`, to be clearer.

Comment: Where in the tex.web can I find the assignment of catcode 16 to a control sequence? In `@<Test if two characters match@>=`, I see `m:=relax; n:=256;` (`m` is catcode of first token, `n` is charcode of first token), where `relax` is 0 ... ?

Comment: @HironobuYAMASHITA Nowhere. The purpose of my answer is to say that: there is no category code 16; Knuth used one of his white lies, in this case.